# How to prevent Spring MVC application to shutdown after closing the terminal?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring MVC application that runs with the normal SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args); statement. When I run it and then close the terminal window, it kills the process. How can I prevent it from shutting down when I close the terminal window?

I'm using OSX 10.9, Mavericks.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can't you run your `java` command with `&` at the end?

Answer (score 3):

As Dave Syer says, you're best to use the `nohup` command which will prevent the child process from hanging up when the terminal window closes.

For example:

`nohup java -jar name.jar 2>&1 >output.log &`

That will send both the standard out and standard error to the `output.log` file. You can omit the `>output.log` and `nohup` will use the default log file called `nohup.out`.

Comment: Thanks @Anju. Are you able to accept the answer if it worked for you?