# How can I get spring-boot to run forever on ubuntu?

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot

I'm trying to run spring-boot on a ***vm*** and have ***nginx*** proxy all request towards it. I've got this working but when I run:

***mvn spring-boot:run***

And my ssh session ends, it will stop the spring boot instance. (*as expected*)

I've also tried adding the `<executable>` config and sym-linking the ***spring-boot jar*** to a service, like so:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <configuration>
           <executable>true</executable>
     </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Then symlink the ***.jar***:

```
sudo ln -s /var/users-java/target/user-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /etc/init.d/user_service
```

Now when I run the service:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/user_service start
```

It will log out:

```
Started [26208]
```

But not run the actual server?! The ***26208*** PID won't show up in my processes either!

Any ideas? Is there an alternate way of running a spring boot app forever? Like the ***forever*** tool in node?

Comment: You could check the logs, when running spring boot as a service they are written to /var/log/<appname>.log (http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html)

Comment: @samlewis - Thanks! Turned out it was running on a port which was being used. I'm doing this all via the terminal on a VM, so I never would've looked their!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent Spring MVC application to shutdown after closing the terminal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20183329/how-to-prevent-spring-mvc-application-to-shutdown-after-closing-the-terminal)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you are running you application in ubuntu, you can use nohup and & to run your process in background. It is simple and I hope it will solve your problem

```
nohup mvn spring-boot:run &
```

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/nohup-execute-commands-after-you-exit-from-a-shell-prompt.html

Comment: For me, this results in 'Unknown lifecycle phase \"&\"'. Tried to run: nohup mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.profiles=staging &

Comment: How do you get logs after running it with this command?

Comment: For some reason nohup ... & makes my application stucks at JPA initialization:

[o.s.o.j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean] Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'. 

@nayandhabarde you can do it in the same directory where you ran your startup command:

less nohup.out

Answer (score 6):

To run a command even after You logout you can use **`nohup`** command.

**`nohup`** stands for "**`no hangup`**." **`nohup`** is a POSIX command to ignore the hangup signal. The hangup signal is, by convention, the way a terminal warns dependent processes of logout.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup

http://linux.101hacks.com/unix/nohup-command/

Your command will look somewhat like

```
nohup mvn spring-boot:run &
```

Answer (score 4):

`sudo mvn spring-boot:start`
Start the project in detached background mode and run even if you close the terminal.
can be stopped with `sudo mvn spring-boot:stop`

Answer (score 1):

`nohup` doesn't support management of a running service.
It's better to use a system that's designed to manage services, like Linux [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) which is configured via the [systemctl](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/systemctl.1.html) command.

See [Spring Boot Application as a Service](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-app-as-a-service) for details.