# Failed to launch Spring boot application into Linux server

Tags: java, linux, spring, spring-boot, ubuntu

I'm trying to deploy my application spring boot into Linux server, so I followed this [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html), and the bellow file represent my unit declaration service:

```
#change this to your workspace
WorkingDirectory=/home/user1/myApp.dev/API/
[Service]
User=user1
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -jar /home/user1/myApp.dev/API/myApp.jar
SuccessExitStatus=143
ExecStop=/bin/kill -INT $MAINPID
ExecReload=/bin/kill -TERM $MAINPID
# In case if it gets stopped, restart it immediately
Restart     = always

Type        = simple
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

when I launch my application I have the bellow error:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: logs/myLogs-api.log (No such file or directory).......Failed to create parent directories for
>   [/logs/myLogs-api.log]

My application cannot find the **logs** folder, but it already exist in the same directory of my jar folder **/home/user1/myApp.dev/API/** .

My logback config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOG_PATH:-logs}/myLogs-api.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_PATH:-logs}/myLogs-api.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <append>false</append>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} %magenta([%thread]) %highlight(%-5level) %logger{36}.%M - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>



    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: It looks like it's trying to create your logs file directory in root as it says Failed to create parent directories for [/logs/myLogs-api.log] (note the leading forward slash)

Comment: Yes, that's why I understand. But I look how to fix this problem :\

Comment: Need to see the code or config where you define the log directory.

Comment: It work when I launch the application on localhost. I'll added for you

Comment: Please share the line from your application.properties file for key "logging.file" and "logging.path"

Comment: @JonckvanderKogel: I don't have this two value in my app.prop :\

Comment: Please try setting the following property in your application.properties, run it locally and see where the logs get directed to: "logging.path=logs". The logs should now be placed in a directory "logs" in the root of your application directory rather than the root of your system but please check.

Comment: in order to launch my application with specific prop file I typed:

sudo /usr/bin/java -jar /home/user1/myApp.dev/API/myApp.jar server 

/home/user1/myApp.dev/API/application-sdev.properties

Comment: Maybe check out this post, it shows quite extensively how to configure Logback with Spring Boot: https://lankydanblog.com/2017/08/31/configuring-logback-with-spring-boot/

Comment: no it's not problem of logback, but problem of prop file that not detected when I typed sudo /usr/bin/java -jar ...

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I think, I'll use this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38088458/how-can-i-get-spring-boot-to-run-forever-on-ubuntu and see if it work correctly

@jww: Thank you for your suggestion I'll duplicate this question in  Unix & Linux Stack Exchange, but it's better that this question not be off-topic and still in Stack Overflow :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your application just doesn't have rights to create folder

> Failed to create parent directories for [/logs/myLogs-api.log]

As a test you can try to run application with sudo.